# add dynamically more addresses with jquery gMap

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap

how can i use a "for each" function for add more addresses on this gmap script?

```
$("#mydiv").gMap({
    markers: [{
        address: document.getElementById("address").innerHTML,
        html: document.getElementById("text").innerHTML,
        popup: true
    }],
    zoom: 4
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't for each iteration but you can do your work as well.

Let's say that you have a json object.

```
 var markers = eval(jsonMarkers);
 for (id in markers) {
    var nMarker = createMarker(markers[id], mapID);
    map.addOverlay(nMarker);
}

function createMarker(pointData, mapID) {
    var latlng = new GLatLng(pointData.Latitude, pointData.Longitude);
    var marker = new GMarker(latlng );
    return marker;
}
```

I hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

so i've try with:

```
        $(function () {

                var myJSON

            $("#address span").each(function () {
                myJSON = [{ address: $("#address span").html,
                            html: $("#txt span").html,
                            popup: true
                        }] ;
            });

            if ($("#address").html != "") {
                $("#mymap").gMap({
                        markers: myJSON,
                        zoom: 4
                });
            }
        });
```

I retrieve data from db access and with asp.net code write in my 2 div elements the addresses and data that i need to show ... but i got errors :\ 
my divs are fill correct ...

Answer (score 0):

so I had to do the same thing: this is using ajax, but the concept is the same. Note the array of objects being passed into the gmaps. [Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344599/jquery-gmap-with-lots-of-dynamic-locations)